# How can I use pubsubhubbub to support a podcast?

Tags: rss, podcasts

Okay, I get the general idea of the distributed RSS model that pubsubhubbub uses, but I'm trying to think of a way to "support" a podcast with it. That is, I want to supplement the bandwidth of a podcast I like, but which needs more bandwidth, or is hampered by the cost of publishing. I'm thinking like some kind of guerilla CDN.

I realize it would be simpler to send money to the podcast. That's not the point.

Is this a possibility? Does it make sense? Am I crazy? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I read about pubsubhubbub, watched their presentation, and even looked into the specs. Why are you trying to use an RSS/Atom distribution protocol with podcasts?

If you want to provide them with more bandwidth why don't you host a copy of the podcasts yourself. They can implement a system on their end that verifies current load against a threshold. When the threshold is met, they redirect visitors to your location where you have a copy. This should be extremely simple.

I mean it doesn't even have to weigh it against a threshold. If you want to offload a percentage of their traffic they can do it with a script on their website. Let's say you want to serve 50% of their traffic. All the script has to do is randomly pick a 1 or a 0. If it is 1, display a link that uses their server, if it's a 0 display a link using your server.

Answer (score 1):

As Marcin Pawelek said, pubsubhubbub has absolutely nothing to do with what you want to do. Specifically, pubsubhubbub is about minimizing *latency*, while what you're trying to do is improve the *throughput*.

As for contributing bandwidth, I thought that bittorrent solved that problem a long time ago...